# How to query a db Model from Flask AppBuilder's Model Class

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-appbuilder

I have a Model created in my Flask app that inherits from `from flask_appbuilder import Model` & now I want to query the Model data to get a specific record using something like `MyModel.query.get(id='someid')` which used to work with Flask-SQLAlchemy Model Class but does not seem to work with the Flask AppBuilder's Model Class. So I'm looking for an equivalent alternative through which I can query a db Model that inherits Model from `from flask_appbuilder import Model`

Answer (score 1):

You can access it as follows :-

```
result =  db.session.query(MODELNAME).filter_by(id=someid).all()
return str(result)
```